# CCA/KCCA for more than two views

Tags: multivariate-analysis, kernel-trick, canonical-correlation

[Canonical Correlation Analysis (CCA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation) *(and its [kernel equivalent (KCCA)](http://eprints.ecs.soton.ac.uk/9225/))* can be used to find linear *(nonlinear)* relationships between two aligned multivariate datasets (or views).

Is there a way to extend this to more than two views? I suppose one way would be to apply CCA/KCCA recursively in a tree structure, but this appears to be rather inefficient. Is there a single optimisation that can achieve this in one step? Or are there any alternative methods that do the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by more than two 'views' you actually mean extending the CCA framework to k-blocks data structure, then you might be interested in

> Tenenhaus, A. and Tenenhaus, M. (2011). [Regularized Generalized
>   Canonical Correlation Analysis](https://studies2.hec.fr/jahia/webdav/site/hec/shared/sites/tenenhaus/acces_anonyme/home/articles/RGCCA%20final%20psychometrika.pdf). *Psychometrika*, 76(2), 257-284.

The corresponding R package is called [RGCCA](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RGCCA/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

This is just a guess. Is it not that CCA can be interpreted as a probabilistic model of the following form?

X | Z ~ N(A*Z,Psi)

Y | Z ~ N(B*Z,Phi)

where X is vector in first view, Y is vector in second view, and Z is latent variable which captures the relation between X and Y.  Psi and Phi are covariance matrices which soak up all the rest of the variations not captured by Z.  Generalization to >2 views is now straightforward.

Learning in this framework would presumably be EM but that is not very efficient.  It is likely that the typical generalized eigenvalue computations for CCA is a more efficient method to get at the maximum likelihood solution in 2 view case, and there might be a generalization to >2 view2 setting?